# Change Password for user in Django when not using the Django User model

Tags: python, django, user-management

I'm halfway through a Django project and we did not start with the default Django User model that is provided. Now it is too late into the project to go back and implement the User model.

The user I have has a set of fields including email, password, firstname, lastname, etc. I created a page to edit the user profile and I'm able to successfully edit any field other than the password field. I tried creating a separate page just to change the password with its own forms, but even then, when I try to save the new password value nothing happens.

models.py

```
class User(models.Model):
    First_Name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    Last_Name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    Password = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    Email = models.EmailField(primary_key=True)
    Address_Line1 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Address_Line2 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    City = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    State = models.CharField(max_length=2,validators=[State_validator])
    ZIP_Code = models.IntegerField(validators=[Zip_Code_validator])
    Country = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Phone_Number = models.CharField(max_length = 20,validators=[Numbers_validator])
    Pickup_Arrangment = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Preferred_Contact = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.First_Name + self.Last_Name
```

forms.py

```
class PersonalManagementForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.users.User

        fields = ['First_Name','Last_Name','Email','Password','Address_Line1','Address_Line2','City','State','ZIP_Code','Country','Phone_Number','Pickup_Arrangment', 'Preferred_Contact' ]
        widgets = {
            'First_Name': TextInput(attrs={'required': True}),
            'Last_Name': TextInput(attrs={'required': True}),
            'Email': TextInput(attrs={'required': True}),
            'Password': PasswordInput(attrs={'required': True}),
            'Address_Line1': TextInput(attrs={'required': True}),
            'Address_Line2': TextInput(attrs={'required': False}),
            'City': TextInput(attrs={'required': True}),
            'State': TextInput(attrs={'required': True}),
            'ZIP_Code': TextInput(attrs={'required': True}),
            'Country': TextInput(attrs={'required': True}),
            'Phone_Number': TextInput(attrs={'required': True}),
            'Pickup_Arrangment': TextInput(attrs={'required': True}),
            'Preferred_Contact': TextInput(attrs={'required': True})
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PersonalManagementForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

views.py

```
def personalmanagemnet(request):
    myuser = is_logged_in(request)
    if not myuser:
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/login/")

    personalmanagemnet_form = PersonalManagementForm(request.POST or None, instance=myuser)
    if personalmanagemnet_form.is_valid():
        personalmanagemnet_form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/dashboard')

    update_context = {
        'update_form': personalmanagemnet_form,
    }
    return render(request, 'personalmanagemnet.html', update_context )
```

Almost all of the answers in stack overflow correspond to using the Django User model so it doesn't help in this case. How is it possible to update a password field manually in django?

Comment: How are we supposed to answer this without seeing any details of your model, views or form?

Comment: Sorry about that. I just added the code

Comment: Password stored in `CharField`? It's an enormous security hole. Take a look at `PasswordField`, also you can view django source code to know the flow with changing password.

Comment: Yea that was done to debug why the password field wasn't getting updated. Either way the password field isn't getting updated.

Comment: why are you reinventing the wheel?